# How to identify last character of string - A character or number?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to identify last character of string, I am accessing the last character using:

```
echo "${VAR: -1}"
```

If it's a character, I want to add a .(dot) before the character and do nothing if it's a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr match ${VAR: -1} '.*[0-9]' >/dev/null || VAR="${VAR:0:`expr ${#VAR} - 1`}.${VAR: -1}"
```

explanation:

```
expr match ${VAR: -1} '.*[0-9]' >/dev/null
```

The first expression returns 1 if last character is a number

```
VAR="${VAR:0:`expr ${#VAR} - 1`}.${VAR: -1}"
```

If the expression returns 1 then the rest of the line assigns var to all chars in var up to but not including the last char, appends a "." character, and appends the last character.